# Freeze the first two rows on vertical scrolling of the page

Tags: html, css, angular

I have implemented a table with horizontal scrolling in angular and have requirement to fix the first two columns while scrolling vertically. I have created a stackblitz to show two tables. What I looking for is that as and when the user scrolls the second table, the first two rows that is Legal Class Name and Fund Name should be fixed.

I tried to apply the following class to the respective tds and it didnt work

```
.stickyRows {
    position: sticky;
}
```

Here is the stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o2ukfs

```css
        th {
            padding: 7px;
            position: sticky;
            left: 0px;
            min-width: 250px;
            width: 250px;
            background-color: #f5f7f7;
        }
    
    
        td {
            padding: 7px;
            min-width: 250px;
            /* max-width: 300px; */
        }
    
        .fundClassesTable {
    
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
    
    
        .cellbgcolor {
            color: transparent;
        }
    
        .btn {}
    
        .tableItem {
            text-align: left;
            border-left: solid 1px lightgrey;
            border-top: solid 1px lightgrey;
            border-right: solid 1px lightgrey;
            border-bottom: solid 1px lightgrey;
    
        }
    
        .rowItem:hover {
            background-color: #f5f7f7;
        }
    
    
        label {
            margin-left: 0.5rem;
            vertical-align: middle
        }
    
    
        .panel-heading {
            color: black;
            border-color: #ddd;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding-top: 5px !important;
            padding-bottom: 5px !important;
        }
    
        .panel-heading .left-label {
            display: inline-block;
            padding-top: 5px !important;
    
        }
    
        .scrollClass {
            overflow-x: scroll;
            display: grid;
            overflow-y:hidden;
            height: 100%;
        }
    
        .panel-heading label {
            margin-bottom: 0px !important;
        }
    
        #FundClass tr:hover {
            background-color: #ECF0F1;
        }
    
        .headcol {
            position: absolute;
            min-width: 300px;
            max-width: 300px;
            width: 5em;
            left: 0;
            top: auto;
            border-top-width: 1px;
            /*only relevant for first row*/
            margin-top: -1px;
            /*compensate for top border*/
        }
    
        .headcol:before {
            content: 'Row ';
        }
    
        .collapsed {
            color: #d6630a;
            font-size: 22px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    
        .expanded {
            color: #d6630a;
            font-size: 22px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
    
        }
    
        .fixed-side {
            border: 1px solid #000;
            background: #eee;
            visibility: visible;
        }
    
    
        .card-body {
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 10px 0;
            background-color: white;
    
        
        }
```

```html
    <div class="card">
     <div class="card-header panel-heading">
      <span class="left-label" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Accounting Fund Classes</span>
          
        </div>
    
    
        <div [ngClass]="{'show': isExpanded}" id="fundClass" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="fundClass_heading"
            data-parent="#fundClass" [attr.aria-expanded]="isExpanded">
            <div class="card-body scrollClass" *ngIf="data">
    
                <table id="FundClass" class="fundClassesTable table-striped">
                    <tr *ngFor="let c of ColumnNames">
                        <th Fund Name scope="col" [ngClass]="c != 'Buttons1'? 'tableItem bold' : 'tableItem cellbgcolor'"> {{ c }}</th>
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let f of data let i=index">
                           
                                <td class="tableItem" style="font-weight: bold"  *ngIf="c == 'Fund Name'">
                                    {{ f.FundName}}
                                </td>
                                 <td [attr.id]="'f.Id'" *ngIf="c == 'Accounting Class Name'"
                                    class="tableItem">
                                    {{ f.FundName}}
                                </td>
                                <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == 'Class ID'">{{f.Id}}</td>
                               
                                <td [attr.id]="'f.Id'" *ngIf="c == 'Legal Fund Class'"
                                    class="tableItem">
                                    {{ f.LegalFundClassName}}
                                </td>
                               
                                <td [attr.id]="'f.Id'" *ngIf="c == 'Invested Amount'"
                                    class="tableItem">
                                    {{ f.InvestedAmount | number : '.2-2'}}
                                </td>
                               
                                <td [attr.id]="'f.Id'" *ngIf="c == 'Vehicle Type'"
                                    class="tableItem">
                                    {{ f.VehicleTypeName}}
                                </td>
                               
                                <td [attr.id]="'f.Id'" *ngIf="c == 'Closure Status'"
                                    class="tableItem">
                                    {{ f.ClosureStatusName}}
                                </td>
                               
                              
    
                                <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == 'Buttons1'">
    
                                    <button *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id]" type="button"
                                        class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1 "
                                        (click)="buttonClicked(f.Id)">Edit</button>
                                    
                                    <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id]" type="button"
                                        class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1"
                                        (click)="buttonClicked(f.Id)">Cancel</button>
    
                                </td>
    
                          
                        </ng-container>
    
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Something to keep in mind: according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), "Table elements as `sticky` positioning containers" are not supported by IE and Safari. Maybe there, Ricardo's Flexbox approach will have the edge on `position:sticky`?

Comment: I have created a new stackbltiz. Actually I need to freeze the first two rows of the second table and not the first. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o2ukfs

Comment: rows Legal Class Name and Fund Name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hope this is what you were looking for:

[image: example GIF]

**app.component.css**

```css
/* Container should define how tall the scrollable content is */
.scrollClass{
  height: 500px;
}

/* tagetting the first <th>; to ensure <th> are scrolled along with <td> */
.fundClassesTable tr:nth-child(1) th{
  z-index: 3;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 2px;
}

/* target all <td> in the first row to be sticky */
.fundClassesTable tr:nth-child(1) td{
  color: red;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 2px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Same as above but with top property as 36px 
because the 2nd "row" is 36px from the top of <table> */
.fundClassesTable tr:nth-child(2) th{
  z-index: 3;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 38px;
}

.fundClassesTable tr:nth-child(2) td{
  color: red;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 38px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[**Forked Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zqsjwi)

#### EDIT:

> Riv's solution has worked for me but i am left with one nagging problem. As I scroll through the fixed rows , I can see the data of the rows visible between gaps of the fixed rows and border of the fixed rows arent visible

Probably not the best solution out there but I would use ::after pseudo selector to create a background for your stickied table cells to hide the background cells when scrolling down.

```css
.fundClassesTable tr:nth-child(1)::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 71px;
  width: 96.7%;
  top: 55px;
  left: 19px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white; //create a white background to cover your other cells when scrolled down
  border: solid 1px deeppink;
}
```

Comment: I use [ShareX](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX) when I'm on windows. If I am on linux, I use [Peek](https://github.com/phw/peek). Both are open-sourced screen capturing tools to immediately create GIFs. Really great tools to communicate ideas when collaborating with others =)

Comment: Please be aware that the `sticky` value is not yet supported in Safari (and IE if anyone still cares).

Comment: Hi samuel, you're right, Safari doesn't support `sticky` but Safari works with vendor prefixed `position: -webkit-sticky`. I have tested it in my ipad's safari, it's working. For reference, https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky. Unfortunately, IE is still not supported.

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for but in my case the borders disappear while scrolling the sticky rows. Any idea

Comment: Borders disappear? Do you mean in the stackblitz I forked or your project? Do check if you have conflicting style rules.

Comment: Anyway, I have edited stackblitz to add a background to fix the gaps showing the rows. You didn't to add another bounty for this, I would have helped you further when I have the time anyway xD

Comment: I have fixed the issue.     .fundClassesTable {

        table-layout: fixed;
        border-collapse: separate; 
        border-spacing: 0;
    }

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the bounty

Comment: I don't think you can reduce bounties... `All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.` see https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: Heya @Tom, if my answer had helped you, could you accept it as the answer please?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your styling

```css
  .card-body{
    height:200px;
    position:relative!important;
    overflow-y:scroll;
  }


  table tr:nth-child(1){

    position :sticky;
    top:0;
    z-index:999;
    left:0;
    background-color:#fff;
}

 table tr:nth-child(2){

    position :sticky;
    top:35px;
    z-index:999;
    background-color:#fff;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: This is not what i am looking for. The column headers are also scrolling and not fixed. I was looking at making the column headers fixed based on scrolling of the browser's bar

Comment: Or Atleast I am looking at the headers being fixed if using the scroll at the card level

Comment: it will be great if you could try your solution on stackblitz

Comment: I have updated the post with new stackblitz. Looking at solution for the second table.rows Legal Class Name and Fund Name should be fixed